# Start service in kernel mode (Vista)

Tags: service, kernel, windows-vista

I'd like to start service before user mode is loaded (in kernel mode). 
The reason is I wanna run several system applications(asm code to write data to BIOS) that are not allowed in user mode (privileges problem).
That's why I got an idea: 1. Write windows service 2. Start and run it in kernel mode 
Is it possible?
Are there any other ways to solve the problem?
I don't usually use Vista (use linux instead), that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows services are user-mode applications. To run in kernel-mode you should write a driver. (So-called "legacy" driver will be enough, see [Driver Development Part 1: Introduction to Drivers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx)).

Comment: "This tutorial will attempt to describe how to write a simple device driver for Windows NT."
Are you sure it will also work on Vista?

Comment: Definitely. Moreover, you need only the DriverEntry.